# Auto-accept Twitter follow requests

Tags: twitter, automation

I have more than 2000 follower requests. I want to approve them all. I thought the API would help, but apparently not. Is there some way to Auto Accept all follower requests with any script or extension?

Comment: Uh...don't you only need to approve followers if you have a protected account? If you want to automatically approve everyone, why not have a regular "unprotected" account?

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Put your account to unprotected state and all pending follower requests will be accepted. Unless, you actually wanted to screen them all one by one.

If you really want to put your account on protected status, you should just revert it to the protected status right after.

Answer (score -1):

I create auto approve scripts with PhantomJS.
https://github.com/nullpos/CagedBird
If you run this scripts many times, you may approve all follower requests...